# partial match excel with different languages

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 different columns in excel and both are containing address lines but in different languages 1 in English and 2nd in Japanese, How can I do the partial match just the based upon the last numeric numbers of both the address.
Please take a look in the attachment to better understand.
[My data set looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opwzm.png)

Comment: copy your data from excel and paste here so that people can test any formula on that data.

Answer (score 0):

So, first issue is address 1 does not have a number on the right.

Now, for address 2 you could use :

```
=right(B1,8)
```

which will bring back the last 8 characters ie the 7 digits with the hyphen. You could match to that result as you wish, assuming the data for adrress 2 is in column B.

Image as proof:
[image]

Comment: I had tried this but each row having the different length for numeric digits due to this it wouldn't work out. do you have any another way to do it?

Comment: Well, I have just thrown together some data in cells to make sure it works, see the image, not sure what is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your data sample, in English address the number you are looking for is separated by comma and is coming at start, For example in 3-10-31, AMAVAMA, you can look for 3-10-31 which is separated by a comma from rest of the address

If this is the case in most of the cells you can use the below formula

Considering your Address 1 is in column B, Address 2 is in column C and the formula is in column A

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(1,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1),$C$2:$C$5),0)>0,1,0),0))
```

the formula is in cell A2 and is an array formula